# All files not downloading

Tags: unix, expect, scp

I'm using scp to copy files from local to remote, 
This is the command I'm using:

```
scp /usr/viryanet/fmosqa/logs/dbg_a.`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H`_EST.log /usr/viryanet/fmosqa/logs/dbg_b.`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H`_EST.log /usr/viryanet/fmosqa/logs/dbg_c.`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H`_EST.log /usr/viryanet/fmosqa/logs/dbg_d.`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H`_EST.log car02fv@goxsd1671:/home/car02fv/`hostname -s`
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [unix.se] or [su]. When you do, you should explain what exactly happens when you run this command, and what you were expecting it to do.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use:
scp /usr/viryanet/fmosqa/logs/dbg_a.`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H`_EST.log /usr/viryanet/fmosqa/logs/dbg_b.`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H`_EST.log /usr/viryanet/fmosqa/logs/dbg_c.`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H`_EST.log /usr/viryanet/fmosqa/logs/dbg_d.`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H`_EST.log car02fv@goxsd1671:/home/car02fv/

/home/car02fv/`hostname -s` this will throw an error like "No such file or directory".If you want to copy all files in hostname directory then create  directory on remote system explicitely using  mkdir `hostname -s` and then use your scp command to copy all files to remote system.

Comment: This is a poorly formatted answer. Please read the SO guidelines before posting. Please edit your response fixing up formatting.

Comment: Yes, I did this already. The issue is that the file names are all the same so I need to put them in different directories.

Comment: Its seems different files by looking at this dbg_a.,dbg_b.,etc.

Comment: @Sneha.N Sorry, let me rephrase that. The file names are all the same for different hosts.